# keras input data ratio setting

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, unbalanced-classes, tensorflow, keras

a newbie question not sure if it's a correct method since I've got an imbalanced dataset
(binary class, class1 12000  class0 2000, class separated in different folder)
I found that my model sometime can't correct get both two class
(see **Original code**)
(literally means class 0 not be sampled at test-dataset)

so is it a good idea to
(see **After Change Code**)

1. resample  both class0 & class1
2. for train former 70% class0 & class1
3. for test latter 30% class0 & class1

Original Code

```
# Shuffle pandas dataframe
df_Full = df_Full.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df_Full.head(20)

#df_Full[:10]
train_test_split_ratio = 0.7

df_Train = df_Full[:int(train_test_split_ratio * len(df_Full))]
df_Eval = df_Full[int(train_test_split_ratio * len(df_Full)):]
```

After Change Code

```
df_class1=df_Full[df_Full.grp==1].sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df_class0=df_Full[df_Full.grp==0].sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

df_Full.head(20)

#df_Full[:10]
train_test_split_ratio = 0.7

df_Train = pd.concat([df_Full[:int(train_test_split_ratio * len(df_class1))],df_Full[:int(train_test_split_ratio * len(df_class0))]])
df_Eval =  pd.concat([df_Full[int(train_test_split_ratio * len(df_class1)):],df_Full[int(train_test_split_ratio * len(df_class0)):]])
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel instead of just using stratified sampling? For instance, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html

Comment: @Sycorax thanks for the info~